# Windows 7 phone static application variables per application sold

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an application which deals with appointments. I want to sell this eventually on a client to client basis.For e.g. if Company 1 buys this app, then the users who download this app on their phones have static application wide variable with companyId = 1 and if company2 buys this then users who download this have companyId = 2 so I can uniquely identify the company. The application is based on selecting available appointments and uses a wcf service in the cloud so I need to identify which company's appointments the user needs to see.

Comment: Refer to KooKiz comments below.He has understood it...

Answer (score 4):

You can't personalize each downloaded copy of the application. Maybe you can provide a login to the company, or add a screen in your app to create a login. Then use this login to uniquely identify the user against your service.